# I can't draw my background. - HTML Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouse, interaction

So, in my code, under the draw function, I have bg.draw(); commented out.

```
    function draw() {
        clearAllCtx();
        player.draw();
        enemy.draw();
        //bg.draw();
    }
```

When I try to uncomment it, the image doesn't appear, and mouse interaction does not work. Any help would be appreciated!!

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henjibansen/GVcPu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the fiddle with the corrections: http://jsfiddle.net/GVcPu/4/

- The entities canvas should be transparent to allow the background to be seen: `style="background: transparent"`
- Be careful with the order of the parameters: `bg = new Background(bgImg,0,0);` and `function Background(xpos, ypos, imgsrc){`
- Be careful with the name of the variables: `ctxBg.drawImage(this.imagesrc, this.xpos, this.ypos);` where the variable is actually called `this.imgsrc` in this function.

Hope it helped!